Identification of different components of Hilbert modular surface?
I'm wondering whether the different components of the Hilbert modular surface can be (naturally?) identified with each other, or if they're at least abstractly isomorphic. (I'd also be interested in this question for Shimura varieties in general). For example, if $X/F$ is the Hilbert modular surface of level $1$ for a real quadratic field $F$, so that it is the moduli space of principally polarized abelian surfaces with an inclusion of $\mathcal{O}_F$ in their endomorphism ring, there should be $h(F)$ (the class number of $F$) many components.
My impression is that the component corresponding to $\mathfrak{c}\in \text{Cl}(F)$ can be described as those abelian surfaces $A$ such that if we consider their homology lattice as an $\mathcal{O}_F$-module, then $[\det H_1(A)]=\mathfrak{c}$. I notice that up to $2$-torsion in the class group, $A\mapsto A/A[\mathfrak{c}]$ then gives an isomorphism between the identity component and the component corresponding to $\mathfrak{c}^2$ (if we choose an integral ideal representative of each class group representative); these identifications are also independent of the choice of representative, and compose in the way you'd expect. Is there a way to identify \emph{all} the components? Are they even abstractly isomorphic (maybe after base extension)?
